# How to move shapes along a path in SFML with C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

I am currently working on a personal project creating an orbit simulator in Visual Studio w/ C++ using the SFML library. This is my very first time working with SFML so there is a bit of a learning curve currently. The "planets" are static at the moment and I'm wondering if there is a way to sort of "attach" the planets onto the orbit path I created in order to move them along their designated path? I know that there will be a good bit of math that will be involved but I am stuck on figuring out how to get them to move on the exact path. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// declares and defines public variables
int screenWidth = 1400;
int screenHeight = 1000;
int windowWidth_x = screenWidth / 2;
int windowHeight_y = screenHeight / 2;

// declares and defines constants
const float dayCalculation = 24.0f;
const float yearCalculation = 365.0f;

class Mercury {
public:
    const string name = "Mercury";
    const float sunRotation = 88.0f;
    const float planetRotation = 59.0f;
};

class Venus {
public:
    const string name = "Venus";
    const float sunRotation = 225.0f;
    const float planetRotation = 243.0f;
};

class Earth {
public:
    const string name = "Earth";
    const float sunRotation = 365.0f;
    const float planetRotation = 0.9958333f;
};

class Mars {
public:
    const string name = "Mars";
    const float sunRotation = 687.0f;
    const float planetRotation = 1.025f;
};

class Jupiter {
public:
    const string name = "Jupiter";
    const float sunRotation = 12.0f;
    const float planetRotation = 0.416667f;
};

class Saturn {
public:
    const string name = "Saturn";
    const float sunRotation = 10756.0f;
    const float planetRotation = 0.4458333f;
};

class Uranus {
public:
    const string name = "Uranus";
    const float sunRotation = 30687.0f;
    const float planetRotation = 0.708333f;
};

class Neptune {
public:
    const string name = "Neptune";
    const float sunRotation = 60190.0f;
    const float planetRotation = 0.666667f;
};

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(screenWidth, screenHeight), "Orbit Simulator", sf::Style::Close);
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    // creates shape for sun
    sf::CircleShape sun(8, 8);
    sf::Vector2f sunPosition(windowWidth_x - 2, windowHeight_y + 2);
    sun.setOrigin(4, 4);
    sun.setPosition(sunPosition);
    sun.setFillColor(sf::Color(255, 255, 0));

    // creates shape for Mercury
    sf::CircleShape planetMercury(10, 10);
    sf::Vector2f planetMercuryPosition(220,220);
    planetMercury.setPosition(planetMercuryPosition);
    planetMercury.setFillColor(sf::Color(100, 92, 133));

    // creates shape for Venus
    sf::CircleShape planetVenus(30, 30);
    sf::Vector2f planetVenusPosition(250, 250);
    planetVenus.setPosition(planetVenusPosition);
    planetVenus.setFillColor(sf::Color(196, 101, 17));

    // creates shape for Earth
    sf::CircleShape planetEarth(40, 40);
    sf::Vector2f planetEarthPosition(300, 300);
    planetEarth.setPosition(planetEarthPosition);
    planetEarth.setFillColor(sf::Color(84, 102, 110));

    // creates a shape for Mars
    sf::CircleShape planetMars(20, 20);
    sf::Vector2f planetMarsPosition(320, 320);
    planetMars.setPosition(planetMarsPosition);
    planetMars.setFillColor(sf::Color(195, 105, 95));

    // creates shape for Jupiter
    sf::CircleShape planetJupiter(80, 80);
    sf::Vector2f planetJupiterPosition(350, 350);
    planetJupiter.setOrigin(40, 40);
    planetJupiter.setPosition(planetJupiterPosition);
    planetJupiter.setFillColor(sf::Color(162, 151, 143));

    // creates shape for Saturn
    sf::CircleShape planetSaturn(70, 70);
    sf::Vector2f planetSaturnPosition(420, 420);
    planetSaturn.setPosition(planetSaturnPosition);
    planetSaturn.setFillColor(sf::Color(248, 223, 182));

    // creates shape for Uranus
    sf::CircleShape planetUranus(60, 60);
    sf::Vector2f planetUranusPosition(500, 500);
    planetUranus.setPosition(planetUranusPosition);
    planetUranus.setFillColor(sf::Color(7, 120, 154));

    // creates shape for Neptune
    sf::CircleShape planetNeptune(50, 50);
    sf::Vector2f planetNeptunePosition(520, 520);
    planetNeptune.setPosition(planetNeptunePosition);
    planetNeptune.setFillColor(sf::Color(106, 141, 222));



    // creates the orbit path for Mercury
    sf::CircleShape mercuryOrbit (25, 25);
    sf::Vector2f mercuryOrbitPosition(windowWidth_x - 15, windowHeight_y);
    mercuryOrbit.setOrigin(12.5f, 12.5f);
    mercuryOrbit.setPosition(mercuryOrbitPosition);
    mercuryOrbit.setOutlineThickness(1);
    mercuryOrbit.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(100, 92, 133));
    mercuryOrbit.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);

    // creates the orbit path for Venus
    sf::CircleShape venusOrbit(40, 40);
    sf::Vector2f venusOrbitPosition(windowWidth_x - 28, windowHeight_y - 10);
    venusOrbit.setOrigin(17.5f, 17.5f);
    venusOrbit.setPosition(venusOrbitPosition);
    venusOrbit.setOutlineThickness(1);
    venusOrbit.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(196, 101, 17));
    venusOrbit.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);

    // creates orbit path for Earth
    sf::CircleShape earthOrbit(60, 60);
    sf::Vector2f earthOrbitPosition(windowWidth_x - 35, windowHeight_y - 20);
    earthOrbit.setOrigin(30, 30);
    earthOrbit.setPosition(earthOrbitPosition);
    earthOrbit.setOutlineThickness(1);
    earthOrbit.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(84, 102, 110));
    earthOrbit.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);

    // creates orbit path for Mars
    sf::CircleShape marsOrbit(90, 90);
    sf::Vector2f marsOrbitPosition(windowWidth_x - 75, windowHeight_y - 50);
    marsOrbit.setOrigin(30, 30);
    marsOrbit.setPosition(marsOrbitPosition);
    marsOrbit.setOutlineThickness(1);
    marsOrbit.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(195, 105, 95));
    marsOrbit.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);

    // creates orbit path for Jupiter
    sf::CircleShape jupiterOrbit(160, 160);
    sf::Vector2f jupiterOrbitPosition(windowWidth_x - 90, windowHeight_y - 65);
    jupiterOrbit.setOrigin(80, 80);
    jupiterOrbit.setPosition(jupiterOrbitPosition);
    jupiterOrbit.setOutlineThickness(1);
    jupiterOrbit.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(162, 151, 143));
    jupiterOrbit.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);

    // creates orbit path for Saturn
    sf::CircleShape saturnOrbit(250, 250);
    sf::Vector2f saturnOrbitPosition(windowWidth_x - 125, windowHeight_y - 100);
    saturnOrbit.setOrigin(125, 125);
    saturnOrbit.setPosition(saturnOrbitPosition);
    saturnOrbit.setOutlineThickness(1);
    saturnOrbit.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(248, 223, 182));
    saturnOrbit.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);
    
    // creates orbit path for Neptune
    sf::CircleShape neptuneOrbit(350, 350);
    sf::Vector2f neptuneOrbitPosition(windowWidth_x - 180, windowHeight_y - 140);
    neptuneOrbit.setOrigin(175, 175);
    neptuneOrbit.setPosition(neptuneOrbitPosition);
    neptuneOrbit.setOutlineThickness(1);
    neptuneOrbit.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(106, 141, 222));
    neptuneOrbit.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);

    Mercury mercury;
    Venus venus;
    Earth earth;
    Mars mars;
    Jupiter jupiter;
    Saturn saturn;
    Uranus uranus;
    Neptune neptune;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        //render
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        window.draw(sun);
        window.draw(planetMercury);
        window.draw(planetVenus);
        window.draw(planetEarth);
        window.draw(planetMars);
        window.draw(planetJupiter);
        window.draw(planetSaturn);
        window.draw(planetUranus);
        window.draw(planetNeptune);
        window.draw(mercuryOrbit);
        window.draw(venusOrbit);
        window.draw(earthOrbit);
        window.draw(marsOrbit);
        window.draw(jupiterOrbit);
        window.draw(saturnOrbit);
        window.draw(neptuneOrbit);

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated remark: Do not create a separate class for every planet. Define a `Planet` class and set its members in the constructor. eg `Planet mercury{"Mercury", 88.0f, 59.0f}`. You probably also want to delegate the drawing of the planet shape and its orbit to `Planet::draw` and `Planet::drawOrbit` methods. Note that that will require quite a few extra member variables and a constructor. But the end result will be cleaner, more dynamic code

Comment: @Botje yes! Thank you, since posting this i actually have removed the seperate classes and put them into one, i also have the math figured out (for the mpst part). My biggest struggle right now is getting the draw method to work from the class as it is giving me errors with the window.draw

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every frame is a day, the planet advances along its orbit by `1/sunRotation` degrees.
Further assuming that the sun is at position (0,0), you can thus get the position at day `d` by standard formula:

```
float angle = (initialAngle + 2 * M_PI * d / sunRotation);
sf::Vector2f pos = distanceToSun * sf::Vector2f{cos(angle), sin(angle)};
```